# Data entry frontend for relational database

Tags: database, excel, forms, sqlite, ms-access

We ( a group of about thirty biologists, and myself, an ecological modeller with experience in programming and some (long time ago) database and database frontend design) need a relational database and a frontend to enter the data of an extended and detailed literature review. The database itself will consist of four tables:

BIB - bibliographic info
SCEN - scenario(s) used in the paper
MOD - model(s) used in the paper
RESULT - results in the paper

There is a one-to-many relationship between BIB -> SCEN, BIB-> MOD and BIB -> RESULTS, where RESULTS contains one MOD and (possibly) several SCEN.

Now the design of the database is not that difficult (there are also some lookup tables), and I am leaning towards sqlite (one file!) but my question concerns the frontend:

What is the easiest way to create this frontend? It should be windows, run locally, and not to time consuming to program?

I used Access in the past, but not everybody has Access. They like Excel, but Excel as a database?????? I don't like the idea - but if it is possible and easy to do?

A webform for a local database? Is this possible and easy to do (I have no experience with web forms)?

Answer (score 1):

Frontend: Access, hands down. For users without Access installed, there is the free Access runtime.

Backend: Access (ACE) is better manageable than SQLite (you already have the frontend to build tables and relations) and is also a single file. For 30+ users hacking away on data entry I would consider SQL Server Express (free).